# Output not displaying all information C++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, cmd, cout

I have to create a program that will output various information about 1343 runners in a marathon. I'm having to import the data from a csv spreadsheet, so I chose to use the getline function. I use simple recursion to fill a string array and then simply use recursion once more to output the data. But for some reason, it only wants to display 300 or so runners' data. Here's the code:

```
int main(){
  string data[1344];
  vector<string> datav;
  string header;
  ifstream infile("C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\cmarathon.csv");
  int i = 0;

  if (infile.is_open()) {

    for (i=0; i<=1343; i++) {
      getline(infile, data[i]);
    }

    datav.assign(data, data+1344);
    for (int i = 0; i < datav.size(); i++) {
      cout << datav[i] << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

I attempted to use a vector in hopes it would help to allocate the required memory to execute the program properly (if that is in fact the problem here).

That code yields the perfect output of runners 1045-1343. I've tried simple work arounds, such as using several `for()` loops to combine the output seamlessly to no avail. Any information would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide example output demonstrating the issue, and your .csv file. If possible please post a reproduction of the issue to an online C++ compiler service like ideone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to copy from the array to the vector.  You can add to the vector directly instead.  Also, it is somewhat bad practice to shadow another local variable at the outer scope.

```
int main(){
  string line;
  vector<string> datav;
  string header;
  ifstream infile("C:\\Users\\Anthony\\Desktop\\cmarathon.csv");

  if (infile.is_open()) {
    // Are you supposed to read the header line first?
    getline( infile, header );
    while( getline( infile, line ).good() )
      datav.push_back( line );

    cout << "Container has " << datav.size() << " lines\n";
    for (size_t i = 0; i < datav.size(); i++) {
      cout << datav[i] << "\n";
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, you still have to break down each line to the individual fields, so pushing back a class or struct as EToreo suggested would be a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'll check back after my next 15 hour programming session to update you on my progress and sanity.

Answer (score 0):

You should try using a struct to represent the fields in the CSV file and then make a vector of that struct type.

Now, loop through the file, reading each line till you reach the end of the file (Google how to do that) - DO NOT assume 1343, you don't have to.  When you read in each line, create a new object from your struct and fill it with the content of that line (you will need to parse it by reading till a tab (\t) or the end of the string) and then datav.push(newObj) it onto your vector.

I suggest using the correct type's in your struct (int for age, string for name, etc.) and passing the string values from the file into those types.  It will be much easier to do things like make a sum of everyone's age.  You will thank yourself (and maybe me?) later.

Comment: I may thank myself later, if I can ever figure this out. But I'd like to thank you now! I'm currently attempting a combination of your answer and George Houpis's. I'm already leagues ahead of where I was before asking for help. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If your not needing to use a vector:

```
for (i=0; i<=1343; i++) {
      cout << data[i] << endl;
    }
```

should work to print out whatever is in the data array
It is also possible to specify a delimeter for the getline function if you need to put different strings in different variables.

However EToreo's method may be more useful to you in the long run.